# If $v=dx/dt$ what is $v^2$ equal to?

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics, classical-mechanics

Just working on mechanics problems right now and I realized that I never actually dealt with a problem like this before.

Usually when I'm solving a differential equation, I would often be able to convert variable $v$ to $dx/dt$. However, this question requires me to convert $v$ into a form related to $dx/dt$.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: If $v=\frac{dx}{dt}$ then $v^2 = \left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2$ but I doubt that is what you are looking for

Comment: $$\sqrt{v^2}=\frac{dx}{dt}$$

Comment: Did you want to see it in differential form? $dv^2 = 2vdv = 2dv\frac{dx}{dt}$? I doubt it, but I’m not sure what exactly you wish to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

If you were asking for $(\frac{d}{dt})^2$, then you were looking at the derivation operator, that is the function which its domain is the set of differentiable functions with respect to $t$, and its codomain is also a set of functions.
$$\begin{array}{lll}
\frac{d}{dt}\colon & \lbrace\text{functions in }t\text{ which are differentiable}\rbrace & \rightarrow \lbrace\text{functions in }t\rbrace\\
& f(t) &\mapsto \frac{d f(t)}{dt}
\end{array}$$
Now assuming that by multiplication, you mean [multiplication of operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Matrices_and_linear_operators), which is just the "[function composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition)", then $(\frac{d}{dt})^2$ means $\frac{d}{dt}\circ\frac{d}{dt}=\frac{d}{dt}(\frac{d}{dt})$. Applying it on a function, say $f(t)$ will give you this;
$$(\frac{d}{dt})^2\big(f(t)\big)=\frac{d(\frac{d f(t)}{dt})}{dt}=\frac{d^2 f(t)}{dt^2}$$
Which is the second derivative of $f(t)$ with respect to $t$.
But you wrote $(\frac{dx}{dt})^2$ which means you are looking at $\frac{dx}{dt}$, this has the derivation already done and you are looking at the result of the derivation. So let's say $x$ was a function on $t$, then $\frac{dx}{dt}$ is a function, not an operator. Therefore, $(\frac{dx}{dt})^2$ is just square of the obtained function.

Answer (score -1):

Well... like that? $$(v = \frac{\mathrm{d}S }{\mathrm{d} t}) \xrightarrow{f: x \mapsto x^2} v^2 =  \frac{\mathrm{d}S }{\mathrm{d} t} \frac{\mathrm{d}S }{\mathrm{d} t} \Leftrightarrow v^2 =  \frac{\mathrm{d}S }{\mathrm{d} t^2} \mathrm{d}S $$

which give us $$v^2 = a * \mathrm{d}S$$

I'm probably wrong, but I though I could give it a try.